# Adding Checkbox programatically, no box visible

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm trying to programatically create a checkbox in my android application with the following code:

```
mItems[i] = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext(), null, android.R.style.Widget_Holo_CompoundButton_CheckBox);
mItems[i].setText(items.get(i).getName());
mItems[i].setTag(items.get(i).getPrice());
mItems[i].setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mFeeContainer.addView(mItems[i], 0);
```

The field gets added with the correct text, however, it only displays the text, there is no check box visible that I can click. If I create the checkbox with new CheckBox(getApplicationContext()) then there is a box but it is in the wrong style so it blends in with my background when it is not checked.

Comment: `new CheckBox(getApplicationContext()` Never do this,...  instead use `new CheckBox(mFeeContainer.getContext()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

- You should never create instances of views based on the application context. Use the Activity context instead, which is intended for all the views related to this context. Although both looks to have a similar behaviour, it can break some stuff in some views and create memory leaks.
- The only constructor thought to be created programatically is `View(Context)`, the other ones should not be called by the user but by the layout inflater. Create a xml file with your checkbox and create a new instance of it using:

`LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.my_checkbox, mFeeContainer, false);`

Now in the xml you can add whatever style you want for your checkbox and all the default styles will be applied.